# Multi line base64 string returns only last line after decoding in Python 3

Tags: python, base64

I have a set of base64 encoded strings. When I try to decode the same, the decoded text just has the last line of the actual string. On any online base64 decoder, the entire text is displayed. I have tried with and without encoding the text to utf-8 prior to decoding.
Here is my code:

```
import base64

encodedStr = "QXJyaXZhbCBNZXNzYWdlDURhdGUgKFVUQyk6IDI2SlVMMjAN"

#with encoding
encodedstr_bytes = encodedStr.encode('utf-8')
decodedBytes = base64.b64decode(encodedstr_bytes)
decodedStr = decodedBytes.decode('utf8')
print(decodedStr)  


#without encoding
decodedBytes = base64.b64decode(encodedStr)
decodedStr = decodedBytes.decode("utf-8")
print(decodedStr)
```

```
Output : 

Date (UTC): 26JUL20
Date (UTC): 26JUL20



Required Output : 

Arrival Message
Date (UTC): 26JUL20
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. The code example doesn't run as described for me. Is the issue that the decoded string contains additional data that you do not want? e.g. it looks like `'Arrival Message\rDate (UTC): 26JUL20\r'` and you only want `26JUL20`? Both versions give the same result for me. The full string, including "Arrival Message".

Comment: When I execute the code, I just get the second line 'Date (UTC): 26JUL20' instead of the full text. I am looking to extract the first line too ('Arrival Message')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string has a carriage return ("\r"), but no linefeed ("\n"). On Windows, this instructs the printer to return to the start of the line and overwrite what is there. The following code behaves the same:

```
print("foo\rbar")  # Prints "bar"
print("fooqux\rbar")  # Prints "barqux"
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!!!It was working fine on linux and any online editor for this reason. print(decodedStr.replace('\r','\r\n')) --This worked in Windows